# Different behaviour of apt update regarding repositories: Hit and Get

Tags: apt

When I `apt update` my system, I often get output lines with `Hit [repo address]` and others with `Get: [number] [repo address] [some size]`. What's the difference between these lines? When should I care about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Get' simply represents getting the file, downloading it, while 'Hit' means the file has not changed since the last check, so there's no need to get it.